# returning variables with new lines after one another python

Tags: python

```
 def function(a):

     var1 = 'stack'
     var2 = 'flow'
     var3 = 'over'

     return ((var1) + '\n'
            (var2) + '\n'
            (var3))
```

The output should be each variable written on another line but my code doesn't seem to work. Any suggestions?

Comment: "does not seem to work" is not a valid description. What did you test ? What's the error you're getting ?

Comment: Why are you passing a parameter called `a`? you're not using it in the body of the function.

Answer (score 1):

The returned string is missing some `+` operators, here's the fix:

```
return var1 + '\n' + var2 + '\n' + var3
```

Alternatively, using a formatted string:

```
return "{0}\n{1}\n{2}".format(var1, var2, var3)
```

Or even more Pythonic, join the strings together:

```
return '\n'.join([var1, var2, var3])
```

Now the string line breaks are alright, don't forget to display them when you call the function:

```
print(function(a))
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the `+` after the newline characters to concatenate all the strings:

Try:

```
return ((var1) + '\n' +
        (var2) + '\n' +
        (var3))
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you missed '+' in your code. It should be:

```
def function(a):

 var1 = 'stack'
 var2 = 'flow'
 var3 = 'over'

 return ((var1) + '\n'+
        (var2) + '\n'+
        (var3))
```